# Scrabble - add values of letters together with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I'm trying to make a scrabble game.

I want to give each letter a value then sum them together if the input box changes.

I've had a search and found how to sum numbers on change but I'm really struggling to figure out how to replace the value of a letter with a number. Here is some code I've modified :

```
$(document).on("change", "input[id ^= 'r1box']", function() {

    var sum = 0;

    $("input[id ^= 'r1box']").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });

    $("#r1totbox_id").val(sum);
});
```

I've got 7 boxes whose id start with 'r1box' and then a total box with id 'r1totbox_id'. At the moment if I put numbers in I get a total but i would like to be able to put 'a' in box 1 and 'b' in box 2 and get a total of 4.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: how do you tie letters with values, at the moment? I can provide you a solution but I'm not sure if it works for you

Comment: I'm trying to do it using an associative array right now then using .each to iterate through. Any solution would help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an array mapping letters to scrabble point values ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions)):

```
var points = [1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10];
```

Then you can take the input and match it to the correct point value, by converting to upper-case and subtracting 65 (A) from the ASCII code value to get the index to the points array:

```
var letter = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
if (letter.length == 1) {
    var letterIndex = letter.charCodeAt(0) - 65;
    sum += points[letterIndex];
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Cp3Fd/

Comment: Thank you so much - I never thought to do it this way!

Answer (score 0):

```
var convert_letters_to_numbers(letter) {
    letter = letter.toLowerCase(); //this prevents any case-sensitive problem
    if (letter == 'a') return 1;
    ...
    /* etc etc etc */
}
```

then, in your code:

```
sum += convert_letters_to_numbers($(this).val());
```

this supposes you'll be using the same values every game. if you want to make it dynamic, you should add a dictionary for mapping (or better, a json object, so you can generate them somewhere else)

```
var mapping_array = new Array();
mapping_array['a'] = 3;
mapping_array['b'] = 1;
....
```

and then iterate through it and return the corresponding value

with your last comment:

```
var dictionary = {"a":1, "b":2};
```

your convert function should just do a simple return statement:

```
return dictionary[letter];
```

and no looping is required